# Photoshop CC Marquee Tool switches to Move Tool when holding cmd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, creative-cloud, marquee-tool

I recently switched from CS6 to CC.
Back in CS6 when selecting the selection tool and holding cmd you could click anywhere on the currently selected Layer and you'd move everything on that layer. Now in CC it basically just switches to that stupid "Move Tool" that always selects the closest element to your cursor and I accidently select stuff that's below what I actually want all the time. It completly disrupts my workflow.

Is there any way of getting the CS6 behaviour back? (Except for switching to CS6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed. It's the same in CS6 as it is in CC, you just have preferences set differently.

Select the **Move Tool** and then **Uncheck the `Auto Select` option** in the Control Bar across the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought It'd be a preference - with different default setting in CS6 (at least for me), I just couldn't find it.